# hardhat deploy MockV3Aggregator not work

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I learn solidity hardhat followed this course Patrick Collins (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ )
At Lesson7 Hardhat Fund Me section Mocking / tags in hardhat 10:49:02,deploy a smart contract (Chainlink MockV3Aggregator).

run this command in terminal  `yarn hardhat deploy --tags mocks`
information in terminal

> yarn run v1.22.19
> warning ../package.json: No license field
> $ /Users/liwei/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/.bin/hardhat deploy --tags mocks
> Nothing to compile
> ✨  Done in 2.34s.

it seems the smart contract isn't deployed.

code below

00-deploy-mock.js

```
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

//声明chainId,MockV3Aggregator的构造函数参数

const DECIMALS = "8"
const INITIAL_PRICE = "200000000"

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    //console.log(`chainId is ${chainId}`)
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    // The deployments field itself contains the deploy function.字段本身包含部署功能。
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    // Fetch the accounts.获取账户 These can be configured in hardhat.config.ts as explained above.
    const chainId = network.config.chainId

    /*
    是否在本地或hardhat网络上，chainId.name pull from hardhat config,
    developmentChains pull from helper-hardhat-config
    includes关键字：看哪些变量是否在数组中
    */
    if (developmentChains.includes(chainId.name)) {
        log("Local network detected! Deploying mocks ...")
        await deploy("MockV3Aggregator", {
            contract: "MockV3Aggregator",
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: [DECIMALS, INITIAL_PRICE],
        })
        log("Mocks deployed!")
        log("----------------------------------------------")
    }
}
// 如何只部署deploy mock文件
module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]
```

01-deploy-funde-me.js

```
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const { networkConfig, developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
//const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")
require("dotenv").config()

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    // we get the deployments and getNamedAccounts which are provided by hardhat-deploy. 也就是hre

    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    // The deployments field itself contains the deploy function.字段本身包含部署功能。
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    // Fetch the accounts.获取账户 These can be configured in hardhat.config.ts as explained above.
    const chainId = network.config.chainId

    let ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = networkConfig[chainId]["ethUsdPriceFeed"] // 参数priceFeed

    const fundMe = await deploy("FundMe", {
        from: deployer,
        args: [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress],
        log: true,
    })
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "fundme"]
```

harhat.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    // solidity: "0.8.17",
    solidity: {
        compilers: [{ version: "0.8.8" }, { version: "0.6.6" }],
    },
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            chainId: 31337,
            // gasPrice: 130000000000,
        },
        goerli: {
            url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 5,
            blockConfirmations: 6,
        },
    },

    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 0, // 这样会默认把第一个账户作为部署合约的账户
            1: 0, //在主网上也会把第一个账户作为部署账户，不管conifg怎么配置，不同网络上的account 0 并不一样
        },
    },
}
```

helper-hardhat-config.js

```
const networkConfig = {
    31337: {
        name: "localhost",
    },

    5: {
        name: "goerli",
        ethUsdPriceFeed: "0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e",
    },
}
// 声明develomentChains

const developmentChains = ["localhost", "hardhat"]
// export config可以让其他文件来交互
module.exports = {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a "deploy" directory in your folder structure in order for the contracts to actually get deployed. The `00-deploy-mock.js` and `01-deploy-funde-me.js` files are supposed to be inside that directory.

Comment: I had my deploy files in a folder called `scripts`. Changing that folder name to `deploy` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the packages from  [FundMe](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/blob/main/package.json) repo, and reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

Update
just fixed
in script 00-deploy-mock.js

when identify the network should be "network.name" not "chainId.name",cause in config file describe by network.name

if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {

Answer (score 0):

remove this line of code  `contract: "MockV3Aggregator",` and make sure that you're compiling your MockV3Aggregator.sol with a compatible solidity version. it should work. Alternatively you could run `yarn hardhat deploy` without the `--tags` flag.

cheers